# CircleCI auto increment docker tag

Tags: docker, circleci, circleci-2.0, circleci-workflows

I am switching from Jenkins to Circle CI (Embarrassed that it has taken this long to get of jenkins).   I have a question about how most people are handling their docker tagging.

My build will fire off each commit (not just pull requests) and it creates a new container and tag each time.   I see that CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM exists but that will increment for each step in the workflow.  This makes it challenging to pass the tag number from one step to another.  I also have seen the CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID is unique to the entire workflow but that is a alpha numeric guid and not as useful as a semantic version.

What is the recommended way to auto increment my docker tags in a CircleCI workflow?

Answer (score 0):

We use the current epoch time as part of ours: TIMESTAMP=$(date +%s)

Answer (score 0):

By creating an artifact after initial build, you can save the previous tag version, and increment with a script on new build.